# Serve Images from Asset Host When Using CSS background-image property in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, cdn

I recently started serving static assets (mainly images) from an asset host for my Rails project.

A small portion of my images are not being served from the asset host because they are displayed using the CSS `background-image` property rather than `image_tag`

Is there are clean workaround for this?  I'd rather not create a "stylesheets" controller because I'm using the `asset-packager` plugin and would like to preserve this functionality.

Thanks!
Moe

Comment: You should accept some answers :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put the full path in the url inside your CSS:

```
background:url({asset_domain}/images/image.png) repeat-x left top;
```

Comment: I've thought about doing that.  But, one of the reasons I setup the CDN was so I could use multiple hostnames in order to parallelize requests.  

Also, hardcoding the asset domain might cause some issues in my dev environment.

Comment: Well, there is a sweet spot between multiple domains and the cost for domain lookups - so perhaps having the css images on a single domain is OK? As for dev, could you use your hosts file to map the request to the local domain?

Comment: Actually - you could add some smarts to asset packager to set this up.   Inject the domain name into the CSS as part of the rake task?

Comment: Super helpful!  Of the four subdomains I have, I'll dedicate one for the CSS background images and then use the remaining three for non `background:url` images.  Thanks Toby.

Comment: Oh, and I'll use a rake task for a creating assigning the asset subdomain within the css.

Answer (score 1):

I do the following running under Rails 3.0.x

```
background: url(<%= image_path("logo.png") %>) no-repeat;
```